# Docker instance not detected in shell despite running normally

Tags: docker, antergos

I’m having some strange behavior from docker. I have docker running locally on antergos, and the containers are up, application is running normally, however when I close the shell window used to start docker and run any docker command from any other shell window, it no longer detects that docker is running. Simple commands like `docker ps` and `docker login` return `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://localhost:2375. Is the docker daemon running?`

It is running though, and the applications running in it are reachable. The mysql instance running in it is also reachable.

My user is in the docker group, and system permissions are correct.

Docker was not started with `sudo`, so it is not a conflict between root and my user.

`htop` shows numerous docker processes running.

`systemctl status docker` shows it as running and numerous subprocesses.

Despite this, no direct docker commands will detect any running processes in shell. What is the issue here? It is not usergroup or permission related. All current efforts to solve this issue have pointed to that, but it has not solved my problem.

I have Arch linux 4.17.6-1 and docker version 18.05.0-ce

Comment: Do you have selinux enabled?

Comment: Nope, no SELinux.

Comment: All docker commands work normally when run from the same shell instance that `systemctl start docker` was run from, but no other shell window recognizes that docker is running.